# How do I declare a variable that increases everytime an action is finished?

Tags: c#, arrays, binary, increment, reverse

I'm a very beginner and just started learning c#. I want to make a simple console app that converts number from decimal to binary.

I have done this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Which decimal number do you want to convert into binary :  ");
    long nr_dec = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    int p = 0;
    long[] nrbin = new long[p];
    int i = 0;

    while (nr_dec > 1)
    {
        nrbin[i] = nr_dec % 2;
        i++;
        nr_dec /= 2;
        p++;
    }
    nrbin[i] = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < nrbin.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(nrbin[i]);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This works halfway. I don't know how many places do I need to store in the array (for example 5 in binary is 101 and I want to store 3 places), that way I want to make that P increases every time I get a number from % and then the array should have p elements but I don't know how to do it (because I am increasing p after the declaration of the array and p in the beginning is 0 so it stores 0 places ) and also I don't know how to make the array show the elements from the last to the first .
//I tried with a list but now I am getting 
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

```
static void Main(string[] args)
            {

        Console.Write("Which decimal number do you want to convert into binary :  " );
        long nr_dec = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        List<long> nrbin=new List<long>() ;
        int i=0;


        while(nr_dec> 1)
        {
            nrbin[i] = nr_dec % 2;
            i++;
            nr_dec /= 2;

        }
        nrbin[i] = 1;



        for ( i =0;i<nrbin.Count;i++)
        {
            Console.Write(nrbin[i]);
        }




        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why not use a `List<>` instead of an array? That way you don't *need* to know how big it has to be.

Comment: Please try to clarify your last paragraph. It should probably be broken up into a few separate sentences. I'm unsure of your intent so I didn't want to try to "fix" it myself.

Comment: I mean I want to reverse the array(or list as you suggest)  because for example 6 is 110 in binary but it shows as 011 so I want to reverse it  and show 110

Comment: Also, get the short, cryptic variable names out of your system now. That kind of nonsense went out of style in the 90s. Variable names should be descriptive and readily convey their purpose without needing to think. With intellisense or some other auto completion, it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: nr_dec means decimal number and nrbin , means binary number whats so hard to get there ?

Comment: Well, for one, they're not even consistent. Why does one have an underscore and the other one doesn't? Secondly, what is `p` supposed to be for? It's not at all obvious without analyzing the code it's involved in. Any other questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Which decimal number do you want to convert into binary :  ");
        long nr_dec = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());            

        var nrbin = new List<long>();           

        while (nr_dec > 1)
        {
            var bin = nr_dec % 2;
            nrbin.Add(bin);                
            nr_dec /= 2;               
        }           
        nrbin.Add(1);
        nrbin.Reverse();
        foreach (var num in nrbin)
        {
            Console.Write(num);
        }           

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I haven't changed the logic of your code just made some changes so that your existing algorithm works. Instead of using the array i have used the List and at the end reverse it so that correct binary is displayed.

Comment: Yes I see , I never used lists before but now I understand better how it works thank you very much